# plots generated by 'plot' and 'ggplot' side-by-side

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, par

Is there a way to put the plot generated by `plot` function and the plot by `ggplot` function in R in one page side-by-side?

It is easy to put plots created by the same function into one page using `par` or `multiplot` function, but I can't figure out the above question.

Comment: you can look at the `gridExtra` package.  It can do this I think.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this using the `gridBase` package and viewPorts.

```
library(grid)
library(gridBase)
library(ggplot2)

# start new page
plot.new() 

# setup layout
gl <- grid.layout(nrow=1, ncol=2)
# grid.show.layout(gl)

# setup viewports
vp.1 <- viewport(layout.pos.col=1, layout.pos.row=1) 
vp.2 <- viewport(layout.pos.col=2, layout.pos.row=1) 
# init layout
pushViewport(viewport(layout=gl))
# access the first position
pushViewport(vp.1)

# start new base graphics in first viewport
par(new=TRUE, fig=gridFIG())

plot(x = 1:10, y = 10:1)

# done with the first viewport
popViewport()

# move to the next viewport
pushViewport(vp.2)

ggplotted <- qplot(x=1:10,y=10:1, 'point')
# print our ggplot graphics here
print(ggplotted, newpage = FALSE)

# done with this viewport
popViewport(1)
```

[image]

This example is a modified version of [this blog post](http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/1007) by [Dylan Beaudette](http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/905)

Comment: You gave a very neat answer. Thanks.

Comment: Where does gridFIG() come from?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. They are both grid-based graphics systems and return graphical objects. Take a look at the grid.arrange function in gridExtra package

Comment: Should that read *If* they are both grid-based graphics systems?

Comment: I may have been reading an earlier version that said 'lattice' and 'ggplot2' ... or this beer I'm drinking has special qualities. One of those up-votes for your answer is mine.

Comment: plot function is not grid-based.  Probably that's what you are referring to, DWin?  However, I've read there are ways to embed plot into the grid system.