# multi paneled graphs: box plot and spagetti plot

Tags: r

I'm trying to create multiple graphs on one panel. I'm hoping for a box plot on both sides of a spaghetti plot.

This is an example of my code:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))

boxplot(h~y,dat,
xlab="Y",
ylab="Incidence 1 (percent)",
main="H",
scales=list(x=list(at=c(1,2))))

xyplot(H~Yr,groups=Subject,type="b",data=data,
ylab="Incidence (percent)",
xlab="Year",
main="Incidence",
scales=list(x=list(at=c(1,2))))

boxplot(h1~y1,dat1,
xlab="Y",
ylab="Incidence 2 (percent)",
main="R",
scales=list(x=list(at=c(1,2))))
```

When I plot my first box plot things look ok (there is still empty space ready to be filled), but once the spaghetti plot is added in, the whole graph is the spaghetti plot (the box plot is erased).

Is there a way to do multiple but different types of graphs on one panel?

Comment: I know there's an optional `layout` argument to `xyplot`, although I'm afraid I've never bothered to use it.

Comment: Look at `gridExtra` and `grid.arrange`

Comment: In your searches of the r-help archives you should include the terms lattice and base graphics. They have different coordiante systems, so mixing them is fairly tricky. You might want to look at Paul Murrell's `gridBase` package.

Comment: Especially, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13022137/1385941) and question. `ggplot2` and `lattice` both use `grid` graphics (so you can replace any `ggplot` references to `lattice` within reason.

Answer (score 1):

As @DWin and @mnel point out, you are having trouble because you are trying to mix base graphics (`boxplot()`) and **grid**-based graphics (`xyplot()`). To get two boxplots and a spaghetti plot in a single figure, you have three main options. The first two will be much easier than the third:

1. Use just base graphics (here `boxplot()` and `plot( , type="b")`), arranging them in a single figure with `par(mfrow=c(1,3)`.
2. Use just **grid**-based graphics (here the **lattice** functions `bwplot()` and `xyplot( , type="b")`), arranging them in a single figure with `grid.arrange()` from the **gridExtra** package.
3. Use a mixture of base and **grid**-based graphics (like you're trying to do now), combining them in a single figure with functions from the **gridBase** package.

The only thing to be said for option 3 is that pursuing it will teach you a lot about the low-level implementation of both the base and **grid** graphical systems!