# How to use R base plots in grid.newpage?

Tags: r, plot, r-grid

Is it possible to "force" R base plots in `grid` package's `grid.newpage`? For example, this works fine:

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
vp1 <- viewport(x=0,y=0.5,width=0.5, height=0.5, just = c("left", "bottom"))
vp2 <- viewport(x=0.5,y=0,width=0.5, height=0.5, just = c("left", "bottom"))
pushViewport(vp1)
grid.rect()
grid.text("vp1", 0.5, 0.5)
upViewport()
pushViewport(vp2)
grid.rect()
grid.text("vp2", 0.5, 0.5)
```

[image].

But if I try something like this:

```
grid.newpage()
vp1 <- viewport(x=0,y=0.5,width=0.5, height=0.5, just = c("left", "bottom"))
vp2 <- viewport(x=0.5,y=0,width=0.5, height=0.5, just = c("left", "bottom"))
pushViewport(vp1)
grid.rect()
print(plot(1,2))
grid.text("vp1", 0.5, 0.5)
upViewport()
pushViewport(vp2)
grid.rect()
print(plot(1,2))
```

R base plot just over-rides `grid.newpage`. Using `par(new=T)` does not help either.

Comment: @james i have learnt to never say something is impossible in R

Comment: The package [gridbase](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridBase/index.html)  by Paul Murrell, author of grid, allows you to do this. For example, see the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridBase/vignettes/gridBase.pdf)

Comment: @Andrie I stand corrected! Though I note that the fundamental differences still impose limitations

Comment: this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13022137/602276

Comment: `fig=gridFIG()`!!! Thank you Andrie!

Comment: @Largh even it is possible to mix the 2 using `gridBase` see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124373/combine-base-and-ggplot-graphics-in-r-figure-window/14125565#14125565) for example ..but why do you want to mix the 2..grid has an equivalent of almost all graphics functions..

Comment: @agstudy some packages make `grid` plots and I wanted to plot them in one window: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000525/how-to-plot-grid-plots-on-a-same-page. Apparently that is not possible.

Comment: @Largh i didn't understand your last link. I am confused. You want to arrange some grid plots in the same page? (I guees the result of `tmPlot`)

Comment: @agstudy Yes. I also thought about the possibility of using `grid` package as an all-around plotting solution when placing several figures on one page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because no-one answered this, I'll do it myself. As Andrie said, the answer to this question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021863/plots-generated-by-plot-and-ggplot-side-by-side/13022137#13022137). You'll need `gridFIG()`function from `gridBase` package to plot R base plots in `plot.new()` instead of `grid.newpage()`:

```
library(grid)
library(gridBase)
plot.new()
vp1 <- viewport(x=0,y=0.5,width=0.5, height=0.5, just = c("left", "bottom"))
vp2 <- viewport(x=0.5,y=0,width=0.5, height=0.5, just = c("left", "bottom"))
pushViewport(vp1)
grid.rect()
grid.text("vp1", 0.5, 0.5)
par(new=TRUE, fig=gridFIG())
plot(1,2)
upViewport()
pushViewport(vp2)
grid.rect()
grid.text("vp2", 0.5, 0.5)
par(new=TRUE, fig=gridFIG())
plot(1,2)
```

[image]