# grid.arrange with John Fox's effects plots

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I'd like to combine multiple effect plots in one window with the effects package, but don't know if there is an easy way to do so.

Here's an example that doesn't work:

```
d1 <-data.frame(x1=rnorm(100,0:10),y1=rnorm(100,0:10),x2=rnorm(100,0:10),y2=rnorm(100,0:10))
require(effects)
require(gridExtra)
plot1 <- plot(allEffects(mod=lm(y1~x1,d1)))
plot2 <- plot(allEffects(mod=lm(y2~x2,d1)))
grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,ncol=2)
```

Comment: `plot` uses base graphics. `gridExtra` functions work with `grid` graphics. The `gridBase` package is one way of getting the two different systems to speak. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999802/how-to-use-r-base-plots-in-grid-newpage/15039605#15039605 for example

Comment: I also thought (incorrectly) that thsi was a base graphics problem, but it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to collect the values of allEffects components and then plot them as an 'efflist'. It looked to me that the plotting was base-graphics, but it is in fact 'lattice' if you follow the class-function trail (or if you read: `?plot.efflist` )

Try this:

```
ef1 <-allEffects(mod=lm(y1~x1,d1))[[1]]
ef2 <- allEffects(mod=lm(y2~x2,d1))[[1]]
elist <- list( ef1, ef2 )
class(elist) <- "efflist"
plot(elist, col=2)
```

[image]

Comment: if, for whatever reason, one really wanted to use `grid.arrange()` here, it is possible to use `grid.grabExpr()` to first capture the output and store it as a grob.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, the result from plotting an `efflist` (which is the result from `allEffects`) is not a lattice graphic; it instead builds up a multipanel graphic of lattice graphics using the `print.lattice` methods.  However, if you plot the individual effects, either by taking the elements from `allEffects` or by using `effect`, then you do get lattice graphics.

Either like this

```
p1 <- plot(allEffects(m1)[[1]])
p2 <- plot(allEffects(m2)[[1]])
```

or like this.

```
p1 <- plot(effect("x1", m1))
p2 <- plot(effect("x2", m2))
```

These can be combined with `grid.arrange`; the catch is that their class is `c("plot.eff", "trellis")` which `grid.arrange` doesn't recognize, so they have to be made into simple `trellis` objects first.

```
class(p1) <- class(p2) <- "trellis"
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```