# Plotting multiple effect plots from logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, gridextra

I have a number of logistic regression models with different response variables but the same predictor variables.  I want to use grid.arrange (or anything else) to make a single figure with all these effect plots that were made with the effects package.  I followed the advice here to make such a graph: [grid.arrange with John Fox's effects plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433966/grid-arrange-with-john-foxs-effects-plots)

```
library(effects)
library(gridExtra)
data <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("group1", "group2"), class = "factor"),obs = c(1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 26L, 1L, 10L, 6L),responseA = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 20L, 0L, 3L, 2L), responseB = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 5L)), .Names = c("group", "obs", "responseA","responseB"), row.names = c(53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L,59L, 115L, 116L, 117L), class = "data.frame")
model1<-glm(cbind(responseA,(obs-responseA))~group,family=binomial, data=data)
model2<-glm(cbind(responseA,(obs-responseA))~group,family=binomial, data=data)
ef1 <-allEffects(model1)[[1]]
ef2 <- allEffects(model2)[[1]]
elist <- list( ef1,ef2)
class(elist) <- "efflist"
plot(elist, col=2)
```

The problem is that, in the models I am using the response variable in the model in the form cbind(response A,no response A), but for the figure I would like to change it to something more clean (like Response A).  I tried changing the y labels by putting a list, but got a warning, and it turned both labels into "Response A".

```
plot(elist, ylab=c("response A","response B"),col=2)
```

Then tried the second method suggestion to change the class to trellis, got an error, so grid.arrange didn’t work either.

```
p1<-plot(allEffects(model1),ylab="Response A")
p2<-plot(allEffects(model2),ylab="Response B")
class(p1) <- class(p2) <- "trellis"
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

Can anyone provide a method to change each y-axis label separately?

Comment: this dataset was produced from actual data using the reproducible() per directions of stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `ef1` and `ef2` variables you created, you can try the following

```
plot1 <- plot(ef1, ylab = "Response A")
plot2 <- plot(ef2, ylab = "Response B")
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ncol=2)
```