# How to plot multiple 'image' and 'plot.default' graphics in a same device?

Tags: r, graphics, plot, spatstat

I have a function, which uses `spatstat`'s [`colourmap`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/spatstat/docs/colourmap) function to generate a color scale to a plot. The `colourmap` function uses the [`image`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/image.html) function to plot the color scale. Here is an example:

```
library(spatstat)

set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 10:1, z = rnorm(10,6,8))

plot_this <- function(x,y,z) {
colpal <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"), bias=1)(20)
colmap <- colourmap(colpal, range = range(z))
layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow = 1), widths = c(9,1))
par(mar = c(4, 4, 2.5, 1) + 0.1)
plot(x, y, type = "p", bg = colmap(z), pch = 21, cex = 3)
par(mar=c(1,0.5,3,2))
plot(colmap, vertical = TRUE)}

plot_this(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z)
```

[image]

I would like to plot several of these plots side-by-side, but my attempts fail:

```
par(mfcol = c(1,2))
plot_this(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z)
plot_this(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z)

dev.off()
layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow = 1))
plot_this(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z)
plot_this(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z)

dev.off()
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(grob(plot_this(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z)), grob(plot_this(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z)), ncol = 2)
```

I found [a tread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/question-on-layout-and-image-plot-td834492.html), where Dr. Paul Murrell says that `image.plot` is incompatible with `layout`. However, I do believe that the problem is solvable. **How can I improve the code to enable plotting using `layout` or `par`?**

I would like to do something like following, but to include the color scale for each plot separately:

```
plot_this2 <- function(x,y,z) {
colpal <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"), bias=1)(20)
colmap <- colourmap(colpal, range = range(z))
plot(x, y, type = "p", bg = colmap(z), pch = 21, cex = 3)
}

layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow = 1))
plot_this2(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z)
plot_this2(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z)
```

[image]

**EDIT:** @IShouldBuyABoat suggested looking into `gridBase`. There is [a nice SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021863/plots-generated-by-plot-and-ggplot-side-by-side/13022137#13022137) for mixing base and ggplot graphics, but I cannot find a working combination of `grid` functions to make the plot. Here is one of the trials:

```
library(gridBase)

plot_this <- function(x,y,z) {
plot.new()
colpal <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "blue"), bias=1)(20)
colmap <- colourmap(colpal, range = range(dat$z))
gl <- grid.layout(nrow=1, ncol=2, widths = c(9,1))
vp.1 <- viewport(layout.pos.col=1, layout.pos.row=1) 
vp.2 <- viewport(layout.pos.col=2, layout.pos.row=1) 
pushViewport(viewport(layout=gl))
pushViewport(vp.1)
par(new=TRUE, fig=gridFIG(), mar = c(4, 4, 2.5, 1) + 0.1)
plot(dat$x, dat$y, type = "p", bg = colmap(dat$z), pch = 21, cex = 3)
popViewport(1)
pushViewport(vp.2)
par(new=TRUE, fig=gridFIG(), mar = c(1,0.5,3,2))  
print(plot(colmap, vertical = TRUE))
popViewport(0)}

graphics.off()
plot.new()
gl <- grid.layout(ncol = 2, nrow = 1)
vp.1 <- viewport(layout.pos.col=1, layout.pos.row=1) 
vp.2 <- viewport(layout.pos.col=2, layout.pos.row=1) 
pushViewport(viewport(layout=gl))
pushViewport(vp.1)
plot_this(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z)
popViewport()
pushViewport(vp.2)
par(new=TRUE, fig=gridFIG())
plot_this(dat$x, dat$y, dat$z)
popViewport(1)
```

Comment: grid is a different plotting paradigm. You probably need to look at the 'gridBase' package to get the capability to mix base-graphics and grid-graphics. (you should also clarify whether the plotting of multiple colorbars , one to each plot region, is what you wanted.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat I tried to `grob()` the plots, but they become plotted when using `grob` (unlike `ggplot2` or other grid-graphics) and seem to override `grid.arrange`.

Comment: Please read comments for meaning before posting further vague descriptions of errors. And then edit your question rather than creating along trail of poorly formatted and insufficiently specific comments.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat Why the aggressive tone? I think I did understand your meaning, although your comment was not that very precise either, especially before the edits. You probably meant something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999802/how-to-use-r-base-plots-in-grid-newpage.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you can only use one kind of layout-control mechanism at a time. The command `layout` is not compatible with manipulating the layout using `par(mfrow)` etc.

A solution would be to remove the `layout` call from the function `plot_this`. Instead, inside `plot_this`, first create a basic plot coordinate system by

```
plot(0,0,xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), type="n", axes=FALSE)
```

Then add the scatterplot using `points(...., add=TRUE)` 
and add the colour map using `plot(..., add=TRUE, xlim, ylim)` where the latter is a call to the `spatstat` function `plot.colourmap`.