# How to plot the restults of ctree in grid?

Tags: r, plot, party, ctree

The results of the plot can be normally arranged in grids. I currently have an issue by plotting the results of the `ctree` function from the `party` package in a grid. This question is a duplicate of a question from 6 years and 8 months ago ([Plot of BinaryTree (ctree, party) ignores plot option of par()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249155/plot-of-binarytree-ctree-party-ignores-plot-option-of-par)). It was opted that gridExtra could provide a solution. However, till now no solution for this issue has been given. Consider the example below.

```
library(party)
library(gridExtra)

#Create random dataframe
dfA <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(50, 5), rnorm(50, 2)), 
                  y=c(rbinom(50, 1, .9), rbinom(50, 1, .1)))

#Duplicate dataframe
dfB <- dfA

#Plot in base R wit par (does not work)
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(party::ctree(y~x, data=dfA))
plot(party::ctree(y~x, data=dfB))

#Try to organize in a grid wit gridExtra (does not work)
treeA <- party::ctree(y~x, data=dfA)
treeB <- party::ctree(y~x, data=dfB)

grobA <- arrangeGrob(plot(treeA))
grobB <- arrangeGrob(plot(treeB))

grid.arrange(grobA, grobB, ncol=2)

Error in gList(list(wrapvp = list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 1,  : 
                                    only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
```

The `arrangeGrob(plot(treeA))` and `arrangeGrob(plot(treeB))` also return an error stating `Error in vapply(x$grobs, as.character, character(1)) :  values must be length 1, but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0`

Does someone known how plot the results of the ctree function in a grid?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
## grab the scene as a grid object
library(gridExtra)
library(gridGraphics)
library(grid)

list.to.pass <- list('plot(ctree(y~x, data=dfA))',
                     'plot(ctree(y~x, data=dfB))')
out<-list()
for (i in c(1,2)){
  print(i)
  
  formula(list.to.pass[[i]])
  
  out[[i]] <- grid.grab()
  
  print(out[[i]])
  dev.off()
}
grid.arrange(out[[1]], out[[2]], nrow = 1,ncol=2)
```

You will get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The plots in `party` and its successor package `partykit` are implemented in `grid` and hence the base graphics options from `par()` such as `mfrow` do not work. You can use `grid.layout()` to achieve similar results. Doing so in plain `grid` is a bit technical but the code should not be too hard to follow:

```
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2)))

pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 1))
plot(treeA, newpage = FALSE)
popViewport()

pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 2))
plot(treeB, newpage = FALSE)
popViewport()
```

[image: party grid]

The reason for the `newpage = FALSE` argument is that by default the plot is drawn on a new page, rather than adding to a potentially existing plot.