# How to combine 4 pairs plots in one single figure?

Tags: r, plot

in advance I am sorry if I am bothering you with trivial questions.

I should made 1 figure which contains 4 different correlation pairwise plots. 
The look of wanted graph can be seen as follows:
[image]

Every single pairwise plot I am making with function pairs():

```
pairs(cbind(AAPL,MSFT,INTC,FB,MU,IBM),main="Frequency=1 Min.",font.labels = 2, col="blue",pch=16, cex=0.8, cex.axis=1.5,las=1)
pairs(cbind(AAPL,MSFT,INTC,FB,MU,IBM),main="Frequency = 2 Min.",font.labels = 2, col="blue",pch=16, cex=0.8, cex.axis=1.5,las=1)
pairs(cbind(AAPL,MSFT,INTC,FB,MU,IBM),main="Frequency = 5 Min.",font.labels = 2, col="blue",pch=16, cex=0.8, cex.axis=1.5,las=1)
pairs(cbind(AAPL,MSFT,INTC,FB,MU,IBM),main="Frequency = 10 Min.",font.labels = 2, col="blue",pch=16, cex=0.8, cex.axis=1.5,las=1)
```

When I combine above pairwise plots through usage of layout function, it is not working (as far as I understood from similar questions layout() and pairs() cannot be combined).

If anyone has an elegant way to combine 4 different correlation pairwise plots, the help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try par(mfrow=c(2,2)) before the plots. Usually this is used to make a grid of plots.

Comment: Or `layout(matrix(1:4, nrow=2))`.

Comment: I think `pairs()` overrides the `mfrow` setting.

Comment: I'm happy to troubleshoot your specific problem if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update, 12014-07-31 11:48:35Z

As [ilir pointed out below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056597/how-to-combine-4-pairs-plots-in-one-single-figure/25057893#comment38979140_25057893) `pairs` somehow overwrites `par`, most likely for some good reason.

@user44037, can you solve your problem working form this code snippet? Copy/pasted from [here](http://nestor.sunderland.ac.uk/~cs0her/Statistics/UsingLatticeGraphicsInR.htm). I believe the solution can be found using `splom` from `lattice`. take a look at `?splom`.

```
 library(lattice) 
 splom(~iris[1:3]|Species, data = iris, 
      layout=c(2,2), pscales = 0,
      varnames = c("Sepal\nLength", "Sepal\nWidth", "Petal\nLength"),
      page = function(...) {
          ltext(x = seq(.6, .8, len = 4), 
                y = seq(.9, .6, len = 4), 
                lab = c("@user44037,", "can you solve your", "problem working form ", "this code snippet?"),
                cex = 1)
      })
```

[image]

#### Initial answer, 12014-07-31 11:35:33Z

Simply following [Avinash directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056597/how-to-combine-4-pairs-plots-in-one-single-figure/25057893#comment38976797_25056597) by copy/pasting code from [the website Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html). Feel free to improve on this example.

I'm happy to troubleshoot your specific problem if you provide a reproducible example.

```
# 4 figures arranged in 2 rows and 2 columns
attach(mtcars)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(wt,mpg, main="Scatterplot of wt vs. mpg")
plot(wt,disp, main="Scatterplot of wt vs disp")
hist(wt, main="Histogram of wt")
boxplot(wt, main="Boxplot of wt")
```

[image]

Comment: Try that with `pairs(iris)` and you will see it does not work.

Comment: Eric Fail, thank you for splom code. Unfortunately, I do not know how to run it on my data. I have 24 time series, belonging to 4 independent groups (4 Pirwise correlation plots): Frequency = 1 Min. ,  with belonging time series AAPL_1m,MSFT_1m,INTC_1m,FB_1m,MU_1m,IBM_1m. Frequency = 2 Min. ,  with belonging time series AAPL_2m,MSFT_2m,INTC_2m,FB_2m,MU_2m,IBM_2m.Frequency = 5 Min. ,  with belonging time series AAPL_5m,MSFT_5m,INTC_5m,FB_5m,MU_5m,IBM_5m. Frequency = 10 Min. ,  with belonging time series AAPL_10m,MSFT_10m,INTC_10m,FB_10m,MU_10m,IBM_10m. Each pairwise plot should show correlation

Comment: I also shared a new question regarding the application of splom() function  in combination of 4 pairwise plots (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076293/how-to-apply-splom-function-in-order-to-create-multiple-correlation-pairwise-p)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide us with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That way we can be much more focused when we try to help you. We avoid wasting your time and you avoid wasting our time.

Comment: Also, now that you have posted a new question, I think you should decide if this question is answered or where you want to take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by using of splom() function as [Eric Fail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305688/eric-fail) suggested:

The solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076293/how-to-apply-splom-function-in-order-to-create-multiple-correlation-pairwise-p).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question might help: [Create a matrix of scatterplots (pairs() equivalent) in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735286/pairs-equivalent-in-ggplot2)

you could create the pairs plots using `ggpairs` in the `GGgalley` package. Since these should then be ggplot objects you could arrange them using `grid.arrange` in the `gridExtra` package.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not appear to work. A longer description why not is at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135157/arranging-ggally-plots-with-gridextra.